# Cambiar url para refrescar token en grails

Tags: grails

Estoy trabajando con `spring security rest`.
Actualmente para refrescan un token se hace mediante la url: `http://localhost:8090/oauth/access_token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=s`

Sin embargo dado que estoy trabajando con una api, me gustaría que que la url fuera `/api/oauth`.

Intenté redirigir en urlMappings pero no funciona, me regresa error 404 notFound.

```
"/api/oauth"(redirect: '/oauth')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que te haga la redireción en urlMappings, tendría que colocarlo así:

```
"/api/oauth" (controller:'oauth', action:'access_token')
```